# Where is the odometer in this car?

Tags: car, old-cars, odometer

I'm not really good with cars. I need help with finding an odometer. Is that the little box with numbers over the wheel? I don't know if the pictures are of any help, so a model is a Chevrolet Impala of '67. Thank you. [image][image]

Answer (score 3):

The odometer on that car is mechanical, and is in the center of the speedometer. In this image, it reads 1.4 miles.

[image: Image taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Jv4dHrR0NY]